# Automatic assignment of remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, remote-access

Is there a way to direct the user automatically to his own PC when Remote Desktop is launched (rather than having the user type in the PC name), other than use pre-saved rdp files?

The situation is this: our office enables remote access only in emergency situations and I would like to give users a USB stick with the pre-configured VPN client and the RDP client (all windows). Since there are many users, it's impractical to manually generate the .rdp files for each one. Hence the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but with caveats. You can assign users a Personal Virtual Desktop that is their own RDP Enabled desktop in AD. You have to setup the Remote Desktop Session Broker, Remote Desktop Gateway, and Remote Desktop Web Access. They go to the website, click "My Desktop", easy from there...
and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 2):

A .RDP file is simple text, so you could script the generation of them (provided you can look them up from a database).

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Users will need to know their PC name, or an admin will have to retrieve it from an asset management system.